# GAMS Cplex Cuts

Tags: cplex, gams-math

I am solving a MILP modelled in GAMS by using Cplex. I am allowing the solver to generate cuts.

Is there a way to get the cuts generated by Cplex displayed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No. CPLEX does not report in any way the cuts it added, so there is no way for GAMS to display them. If you are only interested in the types of cuts generated then take a look at the log: at the very end CPLEX reports how many cuts of each type are active.

If you are desperate to see the cuts that CPLEX added you can export your model from GAMS and then write a CPLEX program in C that uses a control callback. From such a callback you can get the current node LP. This contains the cuts that were added so far and you can extract them from there.